# How to render an element several times

Tags: javascript, reactjs, object, fetch, render

I have a list of items that i have to render(js object). The list looks like:[https://imgur.com/a/lEgfMHd](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RGHwd.png)

```
category: {id: 1, name: "Mac"}
created_at: "2021-08-13T21:07:03.619726Z"
id: 4
name: "iMac 24”"
preview_image: "/media/images/f1cb8efe-13e1-482e-97ca-30ffdf88e3c0.png"
price: 1699
sales: 0
updated_at: "2021-08-13T21:10:07.247422Z"
```

I need to render all of these elements and I don't know how to do it. Now I can render an element if I know his index only like this

```
render() {

        const {items} = this.state

        const countItems = Object.keys(items).length

        const secEl = items[1]
        let url = ''
        if(secEl && secEl.preview_image) {
            url = '*******'
            url = url + secEl.preview_image
        }

        return(
            <div className='store-items'>
                <div className='store-item'>
                    <img className='store-item__img' src={url}></img>
                    <h3 className='store-item__title'>{secEl && secEl.name}</h3>
                    <h3 className='store-item_price'>${secEl && secEl.price}</h3>
                </div>
            </div>
        )
    }
```

I know how to get number of items in the list, but i don't know how to render several times same element with different names, prices and img's.

Help me pls, I'm new in React

Comment: Do you know how to `map` over the array?  Google shows plenty of articles on this.  Here's one: https://linguinecode.com/post/how-to-use-map-react

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create an Array of JSX-Elements.

```
items.map((item, index) => {
    let url = url = secEl.preview_image
    return (
        <div id={index} className='store-item'>
            <img className='store-item__img' src={url}></img>
            <h3 className='store-item__title'>{item.name}</h3>
            <h3 className='store-item_price'>${item.price}</h3>
        </div>
    )
}

return(
    <div className='store-items'>
        { items }            
    </div>
)
```